# Split pandas dataframe with fixed size in MB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to split a pandas dataframe to into smaller dataframes with fixed memory(say 10 mb) before writing them to disk?

I have to write dataframes into AWS S3 and index them into elasticsearch. But elasticsearch/kibana has max size limit of 10mb in roder to successfully index the data. Limit is fixed by the institution , so I can't increase the limit.

Comment: Are you able to set the `chunksize` argument so they are written in smaller batches? That has solved problems for me writing to databases in the past.

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to limit the size of each chunk in MBs ? something like  `print(sys.getsizeof(dataframe))`